# can't require an init.rb file from the command line

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, terminal

I am creating an initial file structure on a project and in the root i have a lib.rb folder which contains a file guide.rb. In the root i also have an init.rb file which i have included below. When i go into the comman line and type ruby init.rb i get the following errors. Can someone help me with this as i am trying to learn core ruby.

```
/Users/em/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': cannot load such file -- lib/guide (LoadError)
from /Users/em/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from init.rb:13:in `<main>'
```

init.rb file is as follows

```
APP_ROOT = File.dirname(__FILE__)

# require "#{APP_ROOT}/lib/guide"
# require File.join(APP_ROOT, 'lib', 'guide')
$:.unshift( File.join(APP_ROOT, 'lib') )
require 'guide'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your directory structure looks like this:

```
.
├── init.rb
└── lib
    └── guide.rb
```

This should work in `init.rb`:

```
require './lib/guide'
```

Comment: What keys you used to print `└──` ?

Comment: @ArupRakshit It's generated by the [`tree` command](http://www.computerhope.com/unix/tree.htm)

Comment: Not working in my bash shell of SUSE OS... Is this a 3rd party package.?